# Angular - ng-click doesn't work

Tags: angularjs

In my view I have:

```
<button ng-click="getPerson()">test</button>
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="person in persons">{{ person.name + ' - ' + person.username }}</li>
</ul>
```

The ul-part works fine, but getPerson() is not called when I click the button? The alert is not shown.

My controller:

```
app.controller('personsController', function ($scope, personsService) {
getPersons();
function getPersons() {
    personsService.getPersons()
        .success(function (persons) {
            $scope.persons = persons;
        })
        .error(function (error) {
            $scope.status = 'Error: ' + error.message;
        });
}

function getPerson() {
    alert('tst');
}
});
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The function needs to be on the `$scope`: Change:

```
function getPerson() {
```

To:

```
$scope.getPerson = function() {
```